# Stopping hadoop after the map phase

Tags: dictionary, hadoop, mapreduce, reduce

Is it possible to stop hadoop after the map phase completes and collect information on the intermediate data (the map output/reducer input)?

Comment: By setting job.`setNumReduceTasks(0)` you can finish the job after the map phase. Moreover, have a look at this similar answer how to keep intermediate data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867608/hadoop-mapreduce-intermediate-output

Comment: If you are using streaming, use -D mapred.reduce.tasks=0 as the config variable

Answer (score 0):

You can specify "-reducer NONE" and the output of the Hadoop job will be the output of the map. More info here: [Amazon MapReduce no reducer job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985609/amazon-mapreduce-no-reducer-job)